# Tcl Error: can't rename to "::sha2::SHA256Init": command already exists

Tags: tcl

I'm having issues with the pki library while using sha256. Here's is the following line of code that I am having issues with:

```
package require pki
set $signature "whatever"
set $keydata "some real 256 RSA key"
set key [::pki::pkcs::parse_key $keydata] 
set sig [some_class::base64_url_encode -input [::pki::sign $signature $key sha256]]
```

And here is the following error message I get:

```
 can't rename to "::sha2::SHA256Init": command already exists
    while executing
"rename ::sha2::${c}-${key} ::sha2::$c"
    (procedure "SwitchTo" line 38)
    invoked from within
"SwitchTo $e"
    ("foreach" body line 3)
    invoked from within
"foreach e [KnownImplementations] {
    if {[LoadAccelerator $e]} {
        SwitchTo $e
        break
    }
    }"
    (in namespace eval "::sha2" script line 3)
    invoked from within
"namespace eval ::sha2 {
    variable e {}
    foreach e [KnownImplementations] {
    if {[LoadAccelerator $e]} {
        SwitchTo $e
        break
    }
    }
   ..."
    (file "/usr/local/naviserverXXXX/lib/tcllib1.15/sha1/sha256.tcl" line 820)
    invoked from within
"source /usr/local/naviserverXXXX/lib/tcllib1.15/sha1/sha256.tcl"
    ("package ifneeded sha256 1.0.3" script)
    invoked from within
"package require sha256"
    (procedure "::pki::sign" line 16)
    invoked from within
"::pki::sign $signature $key sha256"
```

Then I tried doing this:

```
catch {namespace delete ::sha256}  
package require pki
set $signature "whatever"
set $keydata "some real 256 RSA key"
set key [::pki::pkcs::parse_key $keydata] 
set sig [some_class::base64_url_encode -input [::pki::sign $signature $key sha256]]
```

And now I get a different error saying that sha256 is being loaded from a different library:

```
can't rename to "::sha2::SHA256Init": command already exists
    while executing
"rename ::sha2::${c}-${key} ::sha2::$c"
    (procedure "SwitchTo" line 38)
    invoked from within
"SwitchTo $e"
    ("foreach" body line 3)
    invoked from within
"foreach e [KnownImplementations] {
    if {[LoadAccelerator $e]} {
        SwitchTo $e
        break
    }
    }"
    (in namespace eval "::sha2" script line 3)
    invoked from within
"namespace eval ::sha2 {
    variable e {}
    foreach e [KnownImplementations] {
    if {[LoadAccelerator $e]} {
        SwitchTo $e
        break
    }
    }
   ..."
    (file "/web/dev/project-directory/httpd/lib/tcllib1.15/sha1/sha256.tcl" line 820)
    invoked from within
"source /web/dev/project-directory/httpd/lib/tcllib1.15/sha1/sha256.tcl"
    ("package ifneeded sha256 1.0.3" script)
    invoked from within
"package require sha256"
    (procedure "::pki::sign" line 16)
    invoked from within
"::pki::sign $signature $key sha256"
```

I've tried restarting the server and the same error keeps on popping up. Is there a problem with the server loading and not booting with the correct library dependencies?

Comment: What happens when you try without the `package require` at all? Looks like `sign` calls it already. Shouldn't cause a conflict but just curious.

Comment: without package require, it throws an error saying that it needs the pki library.. 
The only thing I have come up with in solving this issue is by starting the server by removing package require pki. Wait until it faults by telling me that it's missing the package require pki. Then include package require pki. and then it works.